# Laravel 4.2 : Route is conflict with subfolder name inside public folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-4

I'm got some problem with Route in Laravel 4.2. Here is details:

I have an example route:

```
 Route::get('users', function(){return 'some-thing'});
```

and the route still work normally at http:://localhost:8000/users.

However, when I create a subfolder inside public folder, its name is "users".

```
--public
  --users
```

That link didn't work and return the folder index. I know that is a big sercurity problem.

How to fix it? Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say a huge security problem, if there is sensitive data in that folder, then it shouldn't be in "public".  You could deny directory listings (assuming Apache virtualhost or .htaccess):

```
Options -Indexes
```

As in Laravel's (and most other frameworks') .htaccess file, it only uses the "Router" if the file or directory doesn't exist.  This is common as shown below:

```
# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I knew that it through a 403 forbiden errror, however it's still not return my users route. That's why I said the route conflict the subfolder name inside public folder. (I'm using Apache serve)

Comment: As I explained below that, this is normal because "users" exists so it won't use the Laravel route in accordance with the standard .htaccess file.  This is why css/js/images are all served fine without specified routes in Laravel.

Comment: Well, I understand now, thanks for your answer. But is there any ways to force it use the route, just further question.

Comment: By modifying the htaccess file, sure, but I think it'd be smarter to reorganize your folder names and always keep sensitive files out of the public folder.